# Rails confirmation popup text does not show if text comes from a controller variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Inside my `submit_tag` confirmation popup in my Rails view, I'm trying to use an instance variable from my Rails controller. In my controller I define my variable like

```rb
@confirmation_msg = "test"
```

Then in my `.haml` view I try to insert the variable as the confirmation prompt text inside my `submit_tag`.

```
= submit_tag "Increase Limits", { onclick: "return confirm(#{@confirmation_msg})", class: "btn btn-danger"}
```

However now my confirmation prompt now pops up as blank, with no text. The cancel & OK buttons are still there. If I change `"return confirm(#{@confirmation_msg})"` to `"return confirm('test')"` I see "test". How come it's blank when I try to use the variable from my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting a string or someting else?

```
@confirmation_msg = test <--- is this a variable that holds a string or you mispelled "test"?
```

If `@confirmation_msg` is, at the end, a string, surround it with (single or double) quotes:

```
"return confirm('#{@confirmation_msg}')"
```

It's a good idea to also escape the content in case you have new lines and/or special characters:

```
"return confirm('#{ j @confirmation_msg }')"
```

(The `j` method is a handy alias of the `escape_javascript` method)

Comment: yes I'm setting `@confirmation_msg` equal to a string (updated my answer). I've tried enclosing the variable in single quotes and tried using the `j` method but the alert popup still shows a blank

Comment: What's the rendered html? are you sure `@confirmation_msg` has, indeed, that value at that moment? do you see any error on the browser's dev tools?

Comment: I'm sure `@confirmation_msg` has the right value because I use `Rails.logger.info` to log it out and I see the right value on my server. I don't have any errors from browser dev tools. Which rendered HTML are you referring to? I can't seem to inspect the javascript alert popup. All of the other rendered HTML is the same as before

Comment: The HTML on the page. You sould have something like `<input type="submit" onclick="......." value="Increase Limits" />` if you inspect the elements on the browser.

Comment: the generated HTML for the `submit_tag` is ```<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Increase Limits" onclick="return confirm()" class="btn btn-danger"```

Comment: so `return confirm()` is blank when I use a ruby variable but if I hard code the string the generated html is `return confirm('test')`

Comment: Did you add the single quotes around the `#{...}` call? they are not there on the rendered html. Where did you inspect the value of `@confirmation_msg`? on the controller? sound like something is overriding it's value and we can't see it. Check if there's something else on the code modifying your variable since `'#{ j @confirmation_msg }'` should work, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193361/discussion-between-victor-cui-and-arieljuod).